# How do I specify a contract's namespace in the XML configuration of a WCF endpoint?

Tags: wcf, namespaces, contract, endpoint, xml-configuration

I've got this WCF service contract (heavily simplified, but pay attention to the namespace it's in):

```
namespace Foo.Services.BarService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface BarContract {... }
}
```

In my `app.config` (client side), I configure an endpoint for some service:

```
<endpoint address="..."
          binding="..."
          contract="Foo.Services.BarService.BarContract" />
```

However, this results in an error saying that no endpoint was found in the client's configuration that supports `BarService.BarContract`. I can only get rid of this error by changing the `contract` attribute value to `BarService.BarContract` (i.e. by removing the namespace).

Why is that? Where could this error come from? Why must I not mention the namespace part of a contract type? Shouldn't that result even more in WCF not finding a matching endpoint?

---

**Reply to the questions in @Ladislav Mrnka's comment below:**

- I am talking about the client side. (I forgot to mention this bit; sorry for that.)
  Can this error possibly come from the server side?
- I generated the above service contract, along with a `BarClient` class that implements it, via Visual Studio's *Add Service Reference* facility. I specified the URL of the `BarService`, which is run by someone else. That's where I also specified that the service should be put in the `Foo.Services.BarService` namespace.
- I was going to use the service directly via the `BarClient` class auto-generated for me, not via a `ChannelFactory<BarContract>`.

Comment: Is the problem in service or client configuration? How did you create the client?

Comment: @Ladislav, I appended a reply to your questions at the end of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating client by *Add Service reference* does not recreate namespace structure from service. All created types and contracts are placed into new namespace defined by the name of the service reference. So I guess you named your service reference BarService. Client configuration must follow names of generated contracts.